# Undesired behaviour when using PagedList in an MVC4 partial view

Tags: c#, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I have a partial view that displays a number of search results from a list. For aesthetic reasons, I display the results two list items per row:

> list item 1 | list item 2
>
> list item 3 | list item 4
>
> etc....

I'm implementing paging with PagedList, and since it's a partial view I'm using `Ajax.ActionLink`s to navigate each 'paged list'. Eg:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("<<", "GetAllProperties", new { page = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "quick-property-search-results" })
```

When the page loads, all items from the list are displayed correctly - two list items per row. However when I click `Next >`, the next items are displayed but the formatting goes off, like this:

> list item 1
>
> list item 2
>
> list item 3
>
> etc...

I tried passing the css class that actually gives me the two-list-items-per-row layout as html attributes to the ActionLinks, but it didn't help.

Does anyone know what's causing this behaviour - and how to remedy it?

**Edit:** added css class and razor code.

```
.result-container { 
    border: 3px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 563px; 
    float: left; 
    height:130px;
}


@foreach (var result in Model)
{
    <div class="result-container">
    // output model data...
    </div>
}
```

Comment: how do you separate the list items? by css or | character?

Comment: By css, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: please add some sample html as well. the paged list css and html would be pretty much enough.

Comment: i had very similar issues, and i was almost certain it was an issue of the css not reapplying itself properly after inserting html via ajax. However it turned out it was a dom element structure issue i was having and that caused my css selectors not to match and therefore not reapply. I'm not certain this will be your answer, but it may be helpful to take a look at your dom after your ajax calls to ensure things are being inserted properly.

Comment: can you also take a look at the generated html with firebug for example, and post the result?

Comment: I'm thinking something like that is causing it - that's why I tried to pass the css class as html attributes. In fact I'm almost certain it is, I'm using a small jQuery plugin to truncate multi-line text and it works on the first 'paged' page, but not the second. How to fix it though?

Comment: I just ran my app in Firefox to see what happens there, tried the paging and worked fine. Tried again in Chrome and it works fine there too. I don't know why it was acting up???

Comment: So now it works fine? In that case i would suspect the browser cache :) .

Comment: Yeah it works now. Must've been that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's lead to some other issues, thing like buttons (that open modal windows via jQuery) aren't working on 'paged' pages, and if I go back a page, a script that I use to truncate multi-line text isn't working and text overflows DIVs. Seems that it's messing up jQuery. Do you have any idea why this happening?

Comment: i'm having the same issue and your solution did not work, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648346/mvc-4-pagedlist-pages-its-makes-my-pages-into-a-list

Answer (score 0):

What does the generated markup look like for @Ajax.ActionLink? I'm guessing it's a matter of binding to your dynamic content after your ajax call. In jquery, you'd use the .on event vs the .click event.